# How do I resolve the Request timeout problem in Azure Function?

Tags: azure, go

I am trying to create a Function APP with Go in Azure.

I am following this resource, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-other?tabs=go%2Cwindows).

Everything works fine when I am running it locally but it gives problems once I deploy it to the cloud.

Code: [github](https://github.com/J0SAL/learning-go/tree/main/go-azure)

**Error Outputs**

1. Through the browser,
   [image]
2. Through VS Code
   [image]
3. Azure Dashboard
   [image]

**My configurations are,**

- OS: windows 11
- Azure subscription: student

Comment: see also the section in [ask] on helping others reproduce the problem

Comment: Letting you know that I had the same issue, the function timed out for me. I'll run more tests later.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue and also solve it, at least on my side. I don't know if this will fix precisely your case now but I'll leave it here in case anyone goes through this same scenario.

I was building the Go program in my Ubuntu 22.04, however, Azure Function images are [based on Ubuntu 20.04](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker), and they share [different Debian](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/what-debian-version-are-the-different-ubuntu-versions-based-on) base distros. Running the function on an App Service Plan I was able to detect the error `GLIBC_2.32 not found`, which was related to [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/58550).

To solve it, I built my Go program locally on **Ubuntu 20.04** (which is the same as it will be running on Azure) and the function worked on the first try running on Azure Cloud.

```bash
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

$ go build <go file>
```

The function I used was set with a Consumption Plan.

For more complex scenarios it might be necessary to tune the build options such as with `go build -ldflags="-extldflags=-static"` or CGO.